# how to select where entire field is uppercase in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all of the rows where the company name is all upper case. The field is called company. I am using SQLyog Community - MySQL GUI v12.2.1 (64 bit).

Comment: `where column = upper(column)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI=UPPER (COLUMN_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select company from tab where company NOT REGEXP '[a-z]' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

try this query

Comment: modified my answer please check